# Direct initialization with empty initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, initializer-list

```
struct X
{
    X() { std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    X({});
}
```

This prints out

```
default ctor
```

and that makes sense because empty brace value-initializes the object (I think).
However,

```
struct X
{
    X() { std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl; }
    X(std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << "initializer list" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    X({});
}
```

For this, I got

```
initializer list
```

I don't find this behavior so strange, but I'm not fully convinced. What is the rule for this?

Is this behavior written in some part of the standard?

Comment: By the way, you can see it's really a [direct-initialization turned copy-initialization in the first case, by deleting the copy c'tor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5653035a1aa8672).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this behavior written in some part of the standard?

Of course. It's all dictated by the rules in [[dcl.init]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#16), emphasis mine to match your initializer:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is
>   the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source
>   type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is
>   not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is
>   not defined.
>
> - If the initializer is a (**non-parenthesized**) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized ([dcl.init.list]).
> - [...]
> - If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - **If the initialization is direct-initialization**, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
>       type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
>       destination, **constructors are considered**. The applicable constructors
>       are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through
>       overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor so selected is
>       called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or
>       expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the
>       overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.
>   - [...]

You supply a parenthesized empty brace-init-list, so only the later bullet applies. Constructors are considered, and in the first case we end up doing a copy-initialization from a default initialized `X`. In the latter case, the `initializer_list` c'tor is chosen as a better match. The rule for choosing this overload is specified in [[over.ics.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.ics.list):

> When an argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), it is not
>   an expression and special rules apply for converting it to a parameter
>   type.
>
> If the parameter type is std::initializer_list or “array of X” and
>   all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted
>   to X, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion
>   necessary to convert an element of the list to X. This conversion can
>   be a user-defined conversion even in the context of a call to an
>   initializer-list constructor.
>
> Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class X and overload
>   resolution per [over.match.list] chooses a single best constructor of
>   X to perform the initialization of an object of type X from the
>   argument initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is a
>   user-defined conversion sequence. If multiple constructors are viable
>   but none is better than the others, the implicit conversion sequence
>   is the ambiguous conversion sequence. User-defined conversions are
>   allowed for conversion of the initializer list elements to the
>   constructor parameter types except as noted in [over.best.ics].

Comment: So basically the best suited constructor is selected.Right?

Comment: @GauravSehgal - Pretty much. [over.ics.list] details how the conversion sequence is chosen.

Comment: wow, you really are an language-lawyer. thank you great help.

Answer (score 13):

To see what's really going on, declare copy and move constructors, compile in C++14 mode or earlier, and disable copy elision.

[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0285e8b07a9dc8b6)

Output:

```
default ctor
move ctor
```

In the first snippet, the compiler looks for constructors of `X` that take a single argument, since you've provided a single argument. These are the copy and move constructor, `X::X(const X&)` and `X::X(X&&)`, which the compiler will implicitly declare for you if you do not declare them yourself. The compiler then converts `{}` to an `X` object using the default constructor, and passes that `X` object to the move constructor. (You must use `fno-elide-constructors` to see this otherwise the compiler will elide the move, and in C++17 copy elision became mandatory.)

In the second snippet, the compiler now has a choice of converting `{}` to `X` (then calling the move constructor), or converting `{}` to `std::initializer_list<int>` (then calling the initializer list constructor). According to [over.ics.list]/6.2, the conversion from `{}` to `X`, which calls the default constructor, is a user-defined conversion, while according to [over.ics.list]/4, the conversion from `{}` to `std::initializer_list<int>` is the identity conversion. The identity conversion is better than a user-defined conversion, so the compiler calls the initializer list constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your specific examples and explanation. It made me much easier to understand.