# In C++ what does standalone curly bracket mean in function parameter?

Tags: c++

For example, consider the following code:

```
class C{};
void foo(C c){}
foo({});
```

Will the compiler default initialize a variable of type `C` and pass it to the function parameter?

Comment: Maybe dupe or at least helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617690/direct-initialization-with-empty-initializer-list (Obviously you couldn't really find this without knowing the exact terms to search for though)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct initialization with empty initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617690/direct-initialization-with-empty-initializer-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the example in the question a bit, adding copy, move and initializer_list constructors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C{
public:
    C() { cout << "default ctor" << endl; }
    C(const C&) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl; }
    C(C&&) { cout << "move ctor" << endl; }
    C(initializer_list<int>) { cout << "initializer_list ctor" << endl; }
};

void foo(C c) { cout << "in foo" << endl; }

int main()
{
    foo({});
    return 0;
}
```

The above run with `g++ -std=c++14 -fno-elide-constructors main.cpp && ./a.out` gives the following output.

```
default ctor
in foo
```

So yes, it does directly default construct the formal parameter for function foo, pretty much ignoring the initializer_list.

However, for a slight change like this `foo({1})` it does call the initializer_list constructor.

```
initializer_list ctor
in foo
```

For a change like this `foo(C{})` it first calls the default constructor and then moves it to the formal parameter.

```
default ctor
move ctor
in foo
```